# How to bind variable with DataRow in DataTable?

Tags: c#, variables, datatable, bind, datarow

I have following code:

```
string car = "cabrio";
int number = 20;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add(car, number);

car = "sedan";
number = 30;
```

And now I want that if those 2 variables ("car" and "number") are changed, the DataRow in the DataTable dt should change automatically with new values.

How can I bind those 2 variables with DataRow?
Is it possible?

BR

**EDIT:**
better example of code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Class object1 = new Class("cabrio", 20);
        public DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        public DataGridView DGV = new DataGridView();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DT.Columns.Add("Car");
            DT.Columns.Add("Value");

            DT.Rows.Add(object1.car, object1.value);

            DGV.DataSource = DT;

            this.Controls.Add(DGV);
        }

        private void btn_ChangeValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object1.car = "sedan";
            object1.value = 30;
        }
    }
}
```

and `Class` I used here:

```
namespace test
{
    public class Class
    {
        public string car;
        public int value;

        public Class(string nameOfCar, int valueOfNumber)
        {
            car = nameOfCar;
            value = valueOfNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

So, now if I want to change values in `DataGridView` by clicking `btn_ChangeValue` it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a `DataTable` / `DataRow` to local variables or fields. There *are* some data-binding mechanisms built into .NET, but they tend to be UI related, and rely on very complicated property change notifications and interfaces like `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `ICustomTypeDescriptor` - very niche stuff.

Perhaps this is an X/Y problem, and if you tell us *why* you're trying to do that, a better alternative can be suggested. Frankly, I also suspect that `DataTable` is unlikely to be part of the solution to most problems.

Comment: Ok, so I have data (simple objects with some filelds like strings and doubles); those objects are strored on list. 
And some fileds of those objects are changing per some time, i.e. 1 minute (in another thread). I want to show those object fileds on table in WinForm (I'm using DataGridView), so i putted those `object` fields to `DataTable` and then used that DataTable as `DataSource` of `DataGridView`. Now my goal is that if those objects will change i want to see it on table in WinForm

Comment: @MateuszWarzyc if you're binding to DataTable using the winforms data-binding API (DataSource and Bindings.Add), this should already just work. Can you show exactly how you're binding the UI?